# Alps classified by SOIUSA

Tags: data

I am searching for a file in any geospatial vector format (Shape, ...) with the Alps classified by [Suddivisione Orografica Internazionale Unificata del Sistema Alpino (SOIUSA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOIUSA) with the 36 sections and if possible also the corresponding subsections as described in detail on the [italian Wikipedia page](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suddivisione_Orografica_Internazionale_Unificata_del_Sistema_Alpino#Alpi_Occidentali).

As mentioned in [this article](http://www.fioridimontagna.it/it/soiusa/Artic-11p-AtlOrAlpi-SOIUSA.pdf) there is also a book by the same author called [Atlante orografico delle Alpi. SOIUSA](http://www.priulieverlucca.it/catalogo/scheda/Atlante-orografico-delle-Alpi.-SOIUSA/184) with some detailed illustrations. My italian is not that perfect, that I would understand everything but there might be some digital files somewhere.

There is a nice image visualising the classification by [Luca Bergamasco](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SOIUSA-sezioni.png), but it is just a PNG:
[image: SOIUSA-sezioni by Luca Bergamasco]

Comment: Migrating to GIS SE at the request of the OP.

Answer (score 4):

You can find a [kml](http://lamontagnedepierrot.tous-cyclos.com/images/communication/0023_soiusa/0023_SOIUSA.kml) of the 36 main to 333 sub SOIUSA zones. Source [lamontagnedepierrot](http://lamontagnedepierrot.tous-cyclos.com/23-soiusa)

Answer (score 2):

The ARPA Geoportale offers a dataset licenced under CC-BY. The [Metadata](https://webgis.arpa.piemonte.it/gpserver_arpa/catalog/search/resource/details.page?uuid=arlpa_to%3A12.03.01-D_2016-09-20-15%3A00) gives a complete overview over the existing versions and the licence.

Direct link to the [WFS-Data](https://webgis.arpa.piemonte.it/ags/services/topografia_dati_di_base/SOIUSA/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS) from Arpa Piemonte. Add in QGIS as WFS-Connection and `Export > Save Feature As...` to local directory.

Answer (score 1):

As the original website is now down, here is a save http://dl.free.fr/r3J7DlTOB pass: `stackexchange`
Actually working on a kmz with 870GR (and all hierarchy), according to https://webgis.arpa.piemonte.it/ags101free/rest/services/top
other kml resources from https://www.homoalpinus.com/alpes/subdivisions/soiusa/

- 36SZ https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1fBzUG3vOMB-l28_ottgYUCibxN4
- 132STS https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1YrtEJDG9ckCoY3rQ0LgeT2_JPDZLINfj

Answer (score 0):

Various online format https://webgis.arpa.piemonte.it/agportal/home/search.html?q=tags%3A%22SOIUSA%22 up to group (873 GR) level